# Can you use jquery in sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-state

I have code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var field = $('#field').val();

if (sessionStorage.getItem('save')) {
    $('#field').val(sessionStorage.getItem('save'));
}

field.addEventListener("change", function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('save', field);
});

});

<input id="field" type="text"></input>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oae8krpm/

But it doesn't seem to work with jQuery, can it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
field.addEventListener
```

`field` is the text value of the field, not the DOM object for the field. Use `$('#field').get(0).addEventListener`, or just jQuery event handling (`on` et al).

```
sessionStorage.setItem('save', field);
```

`field` is the text value of the field at the point you read it on document-ready. If you want to store the new value it was changed to, you'll need to read it again:

```
$('#field').on('change', function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('save', $('#field').val());
});
```